# Why does my BinarySearchTree implementation always report the inserted element as a duplicate?

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm working with BST at the moment and I'm having a few problems with my insertion method although it seems quite logical to me. After debugging, I found out that there's a problem with the assignment of the variables I used, like every time I try to insert a node, it gets inserted as a root and therefore it prints out, "duplicates not allowed" .

For this , I'm working with 4 classes respectively. The following method is in the BinarySearchTree class that extends the BinaryTree class. In the binary tree class I have a protected BinaryTreeNode and other methods for the tree traversals.

Method call from the Main :

```
    int value;
    System.out.println("Number of elements to be inserted: ");
    value = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter next element ");
        num = console.nextInt();
        x.setNum(num);

        tree.insert(x);
    }
```

Problem was with the method call in the main method and not the inset itself.

Comment: Where do you call `insert`? Are you actually inserting two different `DataElement` objects?

Comment: @crush insert is called in the main method, I'm having a for loop that asks the user to insert different values that get inserted in the tree. And I'm inserting 1 DataElement actually.

Comment: Can we see that method, please?

Comment: What do you consider a duplicate? A reference to the same object, or two objects that have the same values?

Comment: Well, I'm trying ti insert different values to the tree, when I insert the very first one, it's not a problem, but as I start inserting the rest it prints out the duplicates message. By the duplicates I mean that in the tree, no 2 nodes can have the same value

Comment: are you reusing the same `DataElement` object, and just changing it's values each time you insert it? If so, then you are going to have problems.

Comment: Where is `x` defined?

Comment: I think that's the problem, because I have a class element that extends the DataElement, and the insert method takes a DataElement type.

Comment: it's defined in the main method and it's of type " element"

Comment: The problem is that you are assigning a reference to the `DataElement` to each `BinaryTreeNode`. If all `BinaryTreeNode` objects hold the same reference to a single `DataElement` object, then when you change the value of the `DataElement` object, all `BinaryTreeNode` objects will see the change.

Comment: @crush I don't get what your trying to say

Comment: I wrote an answer; see if you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in a couple of places. Let's start with your `main()` method.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numElt; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter next element ");
    num = input.nextInt();
    x.setNum(num);

    tree.insert(x);
}
```

As you loop through the elements, you are simply changing the value of a single `DataElement` object (`x`).

When you `insert` this `DataElement` object to your BST, you create a new `BinaryTreeNode`, and then set a reference to this `DataElement` object.

```
BinaryTreeNode node = new BinaryTreeNode();
node.info = insertItem; //Reference set to the object here.
```

Now, ignore the rest of the `insert` method for a second, and go back to your loop. On the next iteration, you are changing the value of the `DataElement` object.

But the `BinaryTreeNode` you just inserted holds a reference to that same `DataElement` object. So, when you change the value in the new iteration, the last `BinaryTreeNode` sees the change too.

Instead, you need to create a new `DataElement` on each iteration of the loop, and pass that to the `insert()` method.

So,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numElt; i++) {
    x = new DataElement(...); //... means whatever constructor parameters it takes.
    System.out.print("Enter next element ");
    num = input.nextInt();
    x.setNum(num);

    tree.insert(x);
}
```

This will give each `BinaryTreeNode` it's own object instance of `DataElement`.

---

#### Detecting Duplicates

Wait, there's more. You defined duplicates as objects with the same value, not same reference. So there is more work to be done.

Here, in your `insert` method, you check if the `insertItem` is the same reference as the last node.

```
if (temp.info == insertItem) {
    System.out.println("We can't have duplicates!");
    return;
}
```

If you want to compare them by value, you should use the `equals` method:

```
if (temp.info.equals(insertItem))
```

This should check them by value, instead of by reference.

Comment: wow, this makes a lot of sense! So you're implying that I create a new DataElement within the loop to avoid referring to the same DataElement object?

Comment: @Sara Yes, exactly. Also, don't forget to compare the `DataElement` objects by value with `equals` or you won't detect duplicates.

Comment: @Sara It looks like you could use that `compareTo` method to check values as well, except check `!= 0` instead of `> 0` or `< 0`.

Comment: The compareTo is used to help in traversal, like whether to go through the left or the right part of the tree

Comment: @Sara Your `compareTo` can return three values: `-1`, `0` or `1`. `0` is returned when the two objects are equal. By checking that `compareTo` is not equal to `0` you are effectively saying it is not a duplicate. Hope that helps.

Comment: the really helps a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`if (temp.info == insertItem)`

to

`if (temp.info.equals(insertItem))`

or

`if (temp.info.compareTo(insertItem) == 0)`

Comment: If `temp.info == insertItem`, then they are a reference to the same object, thus "duplicates".

Comment: That won't make a difference, because that actually means the same thing.

Comment: @Sara it doesn't mean the same thing. The first block compares the object reference. The second block compares their values. However, since you are setting the references, and reusing the same object, they will always have the same values too.